# Send data through query or from store in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

If I want to send a data variable to another component should I send it via query using a router or should I save the data in-store, which method would be better

```
router.replace({
   name: 'routerName',
   query: {
     param: param to send,
    },
 })
```

OR

```
store.dispatch('storeName', paramSave)
```

and get it from store

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.

If the variable has a flag or one time use value, you can use the `query` for passing it.

But let's say you have a complex object, on which you would like to perform some computations and then pass it on to child components (route being same).

In that case it is better to use global store. It syncs the data for you so that you can fetch it where ever you would like.